# How i can reinit jquery tooltips function if ajax-call changed my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, reload

My jquery tooltips plugin working with thumbnails.
After ajax call i adding new thumbnails. 
But i dont know how re-init code from this example:
http://osvaldas.info/blog/elegant-css-and-jquery-tooltip-responsive-mobile-friendly

I changed `$( document ).ready( function(){` to `function show_tooltip(){`. Tooltips working fine. But after secong recalling from ajax tooltips are brokening.

How i can recall function or reset it and call again?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem fixed after changing `.bind` to `.live`

Comment: +1 ed. Thanks for the answer.. My tooltip was not getting initialised after an ajax call... onchanging .bind to .live worked.... I have placed the #tooltip in an external file and included...But now I am not getting the CSS working  for the tooltip. I could see the title attribute is removed and added on mouse enter and leave events.... Do you have any idea how to fix this css issue?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you insert new html you will need to attach the events handler for the tooltip to it. If you are inserting with AJAX, this would be done in success callback of ajax or within ajax page load event of mobile framework.

Comment: I understand it. But i dont know how create handler from this example.